# AWS Lambda node.js reading all rows from RDS database "Runtime.ExitError"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm testing a Lambda function that is supposed to read all rows from an RDS MySQL database (there are 600.000 rows in the table).

**My function**

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
const Knex = require('knex');
//AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-east-1' });

const host = //hidden;
const user = //hidden;
const password=//hidden;
const database=//hidden'sys';

const connection = {
  ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
  host,
  user,
  password,
  database,
};

// createaconnection
const knex = Knex({
  client:'mysql',
  connection,
});

exports.handler = async () => {
  try {
    const res=await knex('ALM_AGGR_LQ_201231_210111_0600_A048_V3_75_GAI').select();
    
    
    const response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            //body: JSON.stringify(res),
        };
        return response;
   }catch(err){
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

**Lambda function specs**

- MB: 10240
- Timeout : 10m
- Ephemeral Storage: 512 MB

However, I'm getting getting the error from aws lambda

```
{
  "errorMessage": "RequestId: 09345ca7-aa01-448e-94f6-c76f3e92254b Error: Runtime exited with error: signal: aborted",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ExitError"
}
```

Comment: What else do the lambda logs tell you, for how long did it run, how much memory did it consume at max? Have you tried just querying the first few rows, not all at once?

Comment: We tried 500 - 600 rows that works (Writing for Boris as we work together)

Comment: In the log it says: 
FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Comment: How large are the rows? Seems like you simply run out of memory, which might very well happen if you try to keep 600k rows (+ all the overhead) of data in memory.

Comment: @luk2302 Would there be any way to circumvent this issue?

Comment: Yes: do not keep so many rows in memory. What are you planning on doing with that data anyway? You surely cannot return the data to the client, a few GB of response data simply exceeds the lambda limits.

Comment: We need to perform CRUD operations on large amounts of data. Is it really not possible? It seems to me that AWS would be able to support this, given what big data companies do.

Comment: AWS can easily handle that, but not  Lambda, that is the wrong tool / service for the job. Use Glue / EMR / EC2 / ECS. Or maybe even Athena or ...